# How to create Connection Pool of GlassFish in Java (ProcessBuilder )

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish

I want to configure GlassFish(such as: create,list..etc JDBC connection pool)
  in Java code(using command line) but not working :

```
String [] c= {"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\glassfish-4.1.0\\glassfish4\\bin\\asadmin.bat","list-jdbc-connection-pools\r\nadmin\r\nadmin"};    
exeCmd(c);
```

**The output using console is:**

C:\Program Files (x86)\glassfish-4.1.0\glassfish4\bin>asadmin.bat list-jdbc-conn
ection-pools
CLI031: Warning: Option "target" is obsolete and will be ignored.
CLI031: Warning: Option "target" is obsolete and will be ignored.
Enter admin user name>  admin
Enter admin password for user "admin">
__TimerPool
DerbyPool
ims2Pool
Command list-jdbc-connection-pools executed successfully.

**But I got this by using java:**

CLI031: Warning: Option "target" is obsolete and will be ignored.
CLI031: Warning: Option "target" is obsolete and will be ignored.
Command list-jdbc-connection-pools failed.

Exit Value is 1

```
private void exeCmd(String[] command) {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        Process process = probuilder.start();

        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        int exitValue = process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("\n\nExit Value is " + exitValue);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Any suggestion?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Create Connection Pool In GlassFish](http://www.javaxt.com/Tutorials/Glassfish/How_to_set_up_a_Connection_Pool)

> before creating pool you have to copy and past your jdbc connector jar file in to glassfish4/glassfish/domain/domain1/lib/etc
>   then restart server 
>   now you create jdbc connection pool